# ODE equilibrium point stable/unstable proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following statement and was asked to evaluate whether it was true or false:

The equilibrium point of the linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = ay + b$ is stable if $a < 0$ and unstable if $a > 0$

I get the sense that this statement is true since I couldn't find a counterexample, but how could i go about proving that it is true?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In this particular case you can just find the exact solution and then use the definitions.

Comment: Differentiate $x \mapsto e^{-ax}y(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Your equilibrium point is $y=-b/a$. If you write the equation as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=a(y+\frac b{a})
$$
you can see that if you start at some $y_0>-\frac b{a}$, when $a<0$ the sign of the right hand side is negative, meaning that $y$ decreases while $y(x)>-\frac b{a}$, getting closer and closer to the equilibrium. If, on the other hand, you start at some $y_0<-\frac b{a}$, when $a<0$ the sign of the right hand side is positive, meaning that $y$ increases while $y(x)<-\frac b{a}$ towards the equilibrium. The equilibrium is thus stable by definition. The opposite happens if $a>0$, making the equilibrium unstable.